# Update xy fields when I move points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, point

I have a point shapefile in edit mode, containing x and y coordinates. When I move the point to another location, the x and y coordinates do not update to the corrected location. I realize the x and y fields, although they are the ones I used to plot the points in the first place, now have nothing to do with the points actual location. Is there any simple way to just move a point in edit mode and have the coordinates automatically update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized how to make the quick fix. Once you move the point using the Editor toolbar:

Open Attribute Table > right click the associated X_COORD field or Y_COORD field > Calculate Geometry > Set properties > Click OK

Now all the XY coordinates, or only selected ones (depending on properties you set) have been updated.